# From Random/Stochastic to Deterministic Markov Chain

Tags: markov-process

I'm interested in a method or  set of methods that would allow to convert  a random/stochastic markov chain into a stochastic/deterministic markov chain. But let me clarify my view.

Given a N states Markov chain, fully filled with nonnegative real random values, and where each row which sum up to 1. How can I remove/reduce the probability of jumps from state to state, such that the new Markov Chain present similarities with a Birth-Death process  (Stochastic/deterministic) while maintening the behavior of the first chain e.g Steady State

Thanks in advance